# Proving Trigonometry Identities $\tan(\frac{1}{2}x+45)+\cot(\frac{1}{2}x+45)=2\sec x$

Tags: trigonometry

How do i prove that

> $\tan(\frac{1}{2}x+45)+\cot(\frac{1}{2}x+45)=2\sec x$?

I managed to arrive at

$$\frac{2 \sec^2 (\frac{1}{2}x)}{1- \tan^2 (\frac{1}{2}x)}$$

but I got stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Be careful!  45 (radians) is not $45^\circ$.  Multiply top and bottom by $\cos^2(x/2)$ and use double angle formula on the denominator.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Because
$$\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}+45^{\circ}\right)+\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}+45^{\circ}\right)=\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}+45^{\circ}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}+45^{\circ}\right)}=\frac{2}{\sin(x+90^{\circ})}=\frac{2}{\cos{x}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ}\right)+\cot\left(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ}\right)&=\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ}\right)+\frac1{\tan\left(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1+\tan^2(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ})}{\tan(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ})}\\
&=\frac{\sec^2(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ})}{\tan(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ})}\\
&=\frac{\sec(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ})}{\sin(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ})}\\
&=\frac{2}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ})\cos(\frac{1}{2}x+45^{\circ})}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sin(x+90^{\circ})}\\
&=\frac{2}{\cos(x)}\\
&=2\sec x
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)